# using JSTL tags in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I want to use JSTL tags in the following scriptlets.
Can any one suggest me how to resolve this?

```
<%=(user == null || user.getPreferredName() == null) ? "" : user.getPreferredName()%>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
${user eq null or user.preferredName eq null ? '' : user.preferredName}
```

try  this one ..

Comment: why downcast someone explain me

Comment: @user3588496 : ya sure try it and check it ASAP

Comment: its showing an error.."multiple annotations found at this line"